# How to Remove a widget from a QToolBar?

Tags: qt, widget, qtoolbar

I'm building my App interface with Qt at the moment.
But one question arises...
I have a QToolbar to which I added a QToolButton with the QToolbar->addWidget method.
The problem is that I want to remove this button later on.

How can I achieve that ?

There is an addWidget method but nothing like a removeWidget correspondence...

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Miky Mike

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `removeAction`. Like this:

```
QAction* MyAction = MyToolBar -> addWidget (MyWidget) ;
...
MyToolBar -> removeAction (MyAction) ;
```